# After resuming Android app from background it freezes

Tags: android, events, android-studio, onresume

**The problem**

I press home button and when I reopen the app from the launch icon i loose part of the layout and everything freezes. i can still use the android interface (homebutton etc.)

*Before background state*

[image]

**Freezed**

[image]

*Here is this if you need.*

[image]

**OnResume Method**

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


    }
```

**OnCreate**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);              

    INSTANCE = this;

    Constants.initializeConstantsFromResources(this);

    Controller.getInstance().setPreferences(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));       

    if (Controller.getInstance().getPreferences().getBoolean(Constants.PREFERENCES_SHOW_FULL_SCREEN, false)) {          
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    if (Controller.getInstance().getPreferences().getBoolean(Constants.PREFERENCES_GENERAL_HIDE_TITLE_BARS, true)) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    }

    setProgressBarVisibility(true);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);                        

    mCircularProgress = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.spinner);

    EventController.getInstance().addDownloadListener(this);                

    mHideToolbarsRunnable = null;

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    buildComponents();                

    mViewFlipper.removeAllViews();   

    updateSwitchTabsMethod();
    updateBookmarksDatabaseSource();

    registerPreferenceChangeListener();

    Intent i = getIntent();
    if (i.getData() != null) {
        // App first launch from another app.
        addTab(false);
        navigateToUrl(i.getDataString());
    } else {
        // Normal start.
        int currentVersionCode = ApplicationUtils.getApplicationVersionCode(this);
        int savedVersionCode = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt(Constants.PREFERENCES_LAST_VERSION_CODE, -1);

        // If currentVersionCode and savedVersionCode are different, the application has been updated.
        if (currentVersionCode != savedVersionCode) {
            // Save current version code.
            Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
            editor.putInt(Constants.PREFERENCES_LAST_VERSION_CODE, currentVersionCode);
            editor.commit();

            // Display changelog dialog.
            Intent changelogIntent = new Intent(this, ChangelogActivity.class);
            startActivity(changelogIntent);
        }

        boolean lastPageRestored = false;
        // gaf - comienzo con la pagina inicial
        String savedUrl = "file:///android_asset/startpage/index.html";
        //String savedUrl = "http://servidor-cade.com";
        //String savedUrl = "http://192.168.1.18:3636";
        addTab(false);
        navigateToUrl(savedUrl);
        lastPageRestored = false;



    }

    initializeWebIconDatabase();

    startToolbarsHideRunnable();
}
```

Comment: Why setContentView() in onResume() ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

should be right after:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Second: Don't set `setContentView(R.layout.main);` on your OnResume. Bundle would save the state. Remove that line.

When you resume the app, the layout shows again (possible even over the current one).

Third: Your code is not clean neither well organized. For example: check the current version to show the changelog should be after `setContentView(R.layout.main);` (follow "First")

**EDIT** Your `onCreate` should be like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Constants.initializeConstantsFromResources(this);

    Controller.getInstance().setPreferences(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));       

    if (Controller.getInstance().getPreferences().getBoolean(Constants.PREFERENCES_SHOW_FULL_SCREEN, false)) {          
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    if (Controller.getInstance().getPreferences().getBoolean(Constants.PREFERENCES_GENERAL_HIDE_TITLE_BARS, true)) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    }
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Comment: i took of the setContentView inside the onResume but same problem, any clues?

Comment: did you put setContentView(R.layout.main); right after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); ? and you don't need onResume for now, remove the entire thing.

Comment: yes but it raises excepction..
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.cade.codigos/org.cade.codigos.ui.activities.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature()

Comment: that's because you're using a requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); let me update my answer.

Comment: i fixed my code as you wrote, 

this message is in the logcat

09-22 15:40:56.121  20279-20286/? E/art﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
09-22 15:40:56.568  20279-20279/? E/CustomWebView﹕ loadMethods(): setFindIsUp [boolean]

When i click the homebutton and open from the launchicon same problem..

do you need to see something else?

Comment: Is that an hybrid app? for the CustomWebView thing. And if you open the app again from the multitasking button? maybe you need to check the stack activity to not generate a new one when pressing the launchicon.  API version? Emulator and mobile?

Comment: yes inside the viewFlipper i put html pages, 
if i open the app from the multitasking menu it works fine, the problem is when i launch it from the icon, 
this problem persists on any emulator since i tried it in android studio with tablets and phones

Comment: there is different flags to avoid that to happen or creating the all thing all over again. For example: FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP will remove any activity and create a new instance. Here you have more info: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html